# How to view a recordset in an access table by means of vba?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

With help of the embedded access vb editor i've written a small code to analyse the field values of my database, and want to finally view the recordsets in a table inside the opened access. As a newbie i can only use Debug.Print to display the field names. Could anyone of you tell me with which statements/commands i can execute my SQL String in order to view the result recordset with values?

```
Debug.Print FinalSQLString
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use a datasheet form and assign the SQL statement to its RecordSource property? Why do you think you need to open a recordset to work with data? Doing so is completely misusing Access and making things much harder for yourself.

Comment: Access can also make things harder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663918/how-to-stop-ms-access-to-change-my-sql-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to display a datasheet containing a VBA instance of a recordset. If the source of your recordset is strQSL, you could however create a table with your results, and open that one, or more elegantly, create queryDef and open it:

```
Sub ShowQd(strQdName As String, strSql As String)
'creates queryDef and display it in a datasheet'
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQdName)
    With qd
        .ReturnsRecords = True
        .SQL = strSql
    End With
    DoCmd.OpenQuery strQdName
End Sub
```

If you focus on displaying things, you could also put a ListBox in a form, set its Number of columns to the number of fields returned by your query (`qd.Fields.Count`), and set your strSql as the RowSource of the ListBox. AND... if you put all your related code in that form, you now have a form that you can import in any db to quickly display what you want :)
Good luck !

Comment: Forms since A2000 have had an assignable Recordset property, so, yes, it is indeed possible to open a recordset, open a Datasheet form, and then set the Datasheet form's recordset to the recordset opened in code. As I said in another comment, there's every few cases where there's any utility in that (as opposed to just assigning the Recordsource property of the datasheet form), but it actually is possible. The only real use I can think of is for displaying disconnected or synthetic recordsets.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton ...and Forms need controls.  So with just a form and a recordset we still are nowhere AFAIK. Querydef is definitely a quicker solution.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the basic recipe:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM myTable")
```

Know that you are using Jet Data Access Objects (DAO) with Access - google that for details.

Expression `(rs.BOF and rs.EOF) = True` indicates there were no rows.

Use `rs.MoveFirst`, `rs.MoveNext` to go to the first and next rows. Test `rs.EOF` after `rs.MoveNext`; when `True`, last row was already processed.

`rs(FieldName)` returns the value of the column named FieldName (a string expression).

`rs(1)` returns the value of the second column.

When done, `rs.Close`.

---

There is no way to hand Access the RecordSet and have it displayed in a Datasheet view. Instead, you will have to create a QueryDef object and use it to perform the query and display the Datasheet view of the results:

```
Dim qd As QueryDef

On Error Resume Next
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "temp"
On Error GoTo 0

Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("temp", "SELECT * FROM myTable")

DoCmd.OpenQuery "temp", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Comment: @rskar Thanks for the explanation. with which vb command/script can i view the result of the query like "SELECT * FROM myTable"?

Comment: Oh - do you mean you want Access to open a DataSheet?

Comment: See answer from iDevlop - the DoCmd.OpenQuery works as if you went into the Queries panel and double-clicked on one of the query icons. What opens is a Datasheet view.

Comment: Code comments: it's better to declare the variables `Dim db As DAO.Database` and `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`. This disambiguates the type libraries. It's not strictly necessary for the Database datatype (I know of no namespace collisions on that), but it's pretty important for the Recordset, since there's also an ADO Recordset type, but it's got different methods/properties.

Comment: I prefer testing `rs.RecordCount = 0` to doing to tests, i.e., `rs.EOF and rs.BOF`. If all you want to know is whether or not records are returned, checking the Recordcount will be sufficient. On the other hand, if you want an accurate count of records returned, you have to do a rs.MoveLast before the RecordCount property can be counted on to be accurate. For testing an empty recordset, though, that's not needed.

Comment: You can assign a recordset to a datasheet form's Recordset property, so it's not true that you can't open a recordset in code and then view the results in a datasheet. Of course, I can't fathom why you'd want to do this, since you can do the same thing by just assigning the SQL string as the RecordSource of your datasheet form and therefore avoid writing code.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - "You can assign a recordset..." I should try that! A MS MVP told me you couldn't, but it would be cool if that works.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - "I prefer testing rs.RecordCount = 0" I've been burned by that approach before when accessing a non-JET DB (such as SQL Server). I've seen RecordCount stuck at -1 whether it should be zero or more. For that reason, I've used COUNT(*) and  rs.EOF and rs.BOF for sake of portability.

Comment: If you're using DAO, `rs.RecordCount = 0` will work. If you use ADO, it won't, as it might return -1 instead of 0 when there are not records. In DAO, RecordCount is rock-solid reliable. My guess is that when you had a different data source, you used ADO instead of DAO.