# How to stop MS Access from changing my SQL code?

Tags: ms-access

I've wrote an SQL query in MS Access and Access made a mess of it, only to show it "graphical".
How do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: This same question has more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930109/how-do-i-force-ms-access-to-retain-its-sql-formatting)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no stopping Access from changing your SQL if you save it as a QueryDef object (ie, using the graphical query editor).  You have (at least) two other options:

1. Build your queries in VBA
2. Store your queries in a table dedicated to queries using a Memo field to store the SQL (this will also require some VBA to take the SQL and execute it or assign it to a temporary querydef, etc.)

You can still use the QBE (query-by-example) window to generate your SQL initially if you want.

Also, if you have a non-Jet backend (MS SQL Server, for example) you can write pass-through queries.  You lose the graphical interface but gain all of the functionality of writing SQL in your backend of choice.  Access won't rearrange the formatting on pass-through queries.

Comment: +1 Well said.  A minor quibble: suggest you drop local from "in a local table".  A linked table can be useful to share the same SQL statements for multiple databases.

Comment: Good point!  I don't use the queries-in-a-table approach myself (I generate most of my queries in VBA).  I hadn't considered the linked table approach, though.  It's something I'll have to think about incorporating in the future.

Comment: I use the queries-in-a-table approach when I get anal retentive about SQL formatting.  I hate the way the query designer "helpfully" reformats my SQL.  But it doesn't really matter unless it's a complex query I'm trying to troubleshoot.  In those situations, formatting it my way helps me keep track of everything.

Comment: Have you implemented your own commenting scheme in your SQL formatting?  I'm thinking one could put comments inside `/*...*/` blocks, for example, and then use a regex to strip the comments out before using the query.

Comment: I like the way you think!  Yeah, I've played with that.  But with queries-in-a-table, I used another field, "Comments", for the ... um ... comments.

Comment: I was thinking specifically about inline comments.  On rare occasions, I've had a query where I though inline comments would be nice.  On the whole, though, they might not be worth the added complexity.  Sometimes I need to remind myself I don't need another pair of [Complicator's Gloves](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx).

Comment: I've been tasked with creating an Access database for my job (first time I've used it) and this really annoyed me. Thank you for the answer as it saved some frustration but really this shouldn't be an issue. I can't think of another database style application I've used on any platform that silently decided to rewrite your SQL queries for you.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a dirty trick : append an `UNION` at the end of the query which is always FALSE.

```
SELECT field_1, field_2 
FROM my_table
UNION select field_1, field_2 FROM my_table WHERE False = True;
```

That's horrible and I'm ashamed to do something like that but it works.